# Draw new attention to question after editing?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions

I recently asked this question on Stack Overflow: [Add an event to an existing control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72535485/add-an-event-to-an-existing-control)

One comment asked to clarify some things (with good reason), and it got two downvotes - probably because of the lack of examples of what I have tried.

I have now edited the question with some examples, but now my question seems to have 'drowned'.

Is there a good and acceptable conduct to draw attention to the question again?

Or should I simply ask the full question again? Is this regarded as acceptable?

Comment: See also: [If I didn't get an answer, should I post a new question or edit the original one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110665/if-i-didnt-get-an-answer-should-i-post-a-new-question-or-edit-the-original-one)

Comment: Somewhat related: The upcoming *[Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground)*.